# Is it possible to apply virtualService and Destination to the specified version of the POD

Tags: istio

I have two http services A and B, and each service has two versions v1 and v2.

If A(v1) calls B, eg. use http://b:8080, both B(v1) and B(v2) can answer the call.

When A (v2) calls B, only B (v2) gets the call.

How should I define `virtualService` and Destination rules in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to match the pod from where the traffic is coming from with `sourceLabels` and the route it to the specific `subsets`. Here's an example of how that might look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: route-av1-bv1-2
spec:
  hosts:
  - service-b
  http:
#Match the traffic from App-A-version-1 towards App-B versions 1 & 2
  - match:
    - sourceLabels:
        app: av1
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: service-b
          subset: v1
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: service-b
          subset: v2  
#Match the traffic from App-A-version-2 towards only App-B-version-2
  - match:
    - sourceLabels:
        app: av2
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: service-b
          subset: v2
```

And the `DestinationRule`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: route-av1-bv1-2
spec:
  host: service-b
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      app: bv1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      app: bv2
```

Istio [traffic management](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/) sections describes the `VirtualService` and `DestinationRule` very well along with some good examples.